# How in datetimepicker to show time in 0-23 hours?

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker

Working with datetimepicker https://getdatepicker.com/5-4/Usage/
I did not find has it options to show time in 0-23 hours ?

Thanks!

Comment: did you check [this](https://getdatepicker.com/5-4/Options/#format) Give `H` in capital for 0 to 23 hours in format

Comment: Thanks!
Has it button to SelectValue/ClosePicker ? I try option showClose, but it does not work
and I have to click out of picker to close picker. I do:
            $('#published_at').datetimepicker(
                {
                    inline: false,
                    sideBySide: true,
                    useCurrent: false,
                    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm',
                    defaultDate: "{{ $educationData->published_at_calendar_formatted }}",

                    showClose: true
                }
            );